# SQL query to find all names where same user_id count > 3

Tags: sql

I have following table and I want to display all names along with the user_id where unique user_id count>3.

```
user_id  names
--------------
701      Name1
701      Name2
701      Name3
701      Name4     
702      Name5
702      Name6
703      Name7
703      Name8
```

**For Example:**

In Above table only user_id **701** has more than **3** names. So my output should come like this

```
    user_id    names
    ---------------
    701        Name1
    701        Name2
    701        Name3
    701        Name4
```

I have tried following query but not getting expected result:

```
SELECT user_id,names FROM table GROUP BY user_id HAVING count(user_id) > 3
```

This query only shows 1st row of expected output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
select user_id, names
  from table 
 where user_id in (select user_id
                     from table
                    group by user_id
                   having count(*) > 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Most databases support ANSI standard window functions.  You can do this as:

```
select user_id, names
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by name) as cnt
      from table t
     ) t
where cnt > 3;
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Fair enough.  I'm deleting my comments.